# Can Git differentially store GZip files?

Tags: git, gzip

Does Git store text compressed with Gzip as binary files or can it tell that it's text and store the changes between updates to the files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git does not attempt to look into any binary files. In fact, it doesn't even attempt to look into text files. It doesn't store updates at all. What it does is store the full contents of every single file, but it does [delta-compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) across the entire object store. So the data that's stored on-disk is in fact just updates (hence "delta-compression"), but Git itself sees full files.

That said, no, Git does not attempt to decompress gzipped-compressed files in order to re-compress itself. What this means is text that's compressed with gzip will have about the same performance as any other compressed format (e.g. images), which is to say, there won't be much savings.

Comment: So if I decompressed the text files it could save me space in the long run?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: I suppose so, although I have to wonder how large your text files are and how frequently they change (and why you're storing them gzipped to begin with).

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: Probably. I just did an experiment: 10,000 versions of a text file (about 1500 lines, 44 KB) with a minor change on the first line of each, uncompressed and compressed in two separate git repositories (gzip reduces the size to 16 KB). Both repositories ended up with the `.git` directory occupying 241 MB. After `git gc`, the version with the uncompressed files occupies 6.2 MB; the version with the compressed files occupies 19 MB. Apparently git was able to take advantage of the common content in the uncompressed files, but not in the compressed files.

Comment: @KeithThompson I wonder how that scales. If the file was 80mb or 800mb, I wonder what happens. Do you have a gist or something of your test script?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: The output of max-level gzip compression should be incompressible (by gzip, at least). Generally, the output of a compression algorithm is indistinguishable from random data when fed back into that same compression algorithm. If not, then it's a bad algorithm. Git may be able to squeeze a bit of extra compression by virtue of doing delta-compression across the entire object store at once, but in general, when you put compressed files into Git, you should assume they won't be compressed any further. Note that Keith had 19MB of compressed data and Git only brought that to 16MB.